# CSS Gradient border with :after

Tags: css, border, gradient, linear-gradients

css question.

Is it possible to add a gradient to a border that reflects to the div above?

I can add a solid color, cannot seem to find something for a gradient.

[current status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CEvg.jpg)

```css
 .offerBox {
  width: 360px;
  height: 170px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fcd651 0%,#f9c100 100%); 

 }
 
 .offerBox:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-top-color: #f9c100;
  border-width: 30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="offerBox"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: if you need align center bottom you can use transform:rotate(45deg) translate(-50%, 0); in .offerBox:after and update top as you need. check my update answer

Answer (score 2):

You can remove border and apply gradient to `:after` background

use  `transform: rotate(45deg);` to give it the triangle look.
and `z-index: -1;` will push it below the offer div.

```
.offerBox:after {
      top: calc(100% - 15px);
      left: 50%;
      content: " ";
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
      position: absolute;
      pointer-events: none;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #fcd651 0%, #f9c100 100%);
      margin-left: -30px;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

**SNIPPET**

```css
.offerBox {
  width: 360px;
  height: 170px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fcd651 0%, #f9c100 100%);
}

.offerBox:after {
  top: calc(100% - 15px);
  left: 50%;
  content: " ";
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fcd651 0%, #f9c100 100%);
  margin-left: -30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="offerBox"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nadir!

Answer (score 2):

You can use as a background, you can change color of gradient as you need. if you need align center bottom you can use`transform:rotate(45deg) translate(-50%, 0);` in `.offerBox:after`and update top as you need

```css
.offerBox {
    width: 360px;
    height: 170px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #fcd651 0%, #f9c100 100%);
}
.offerBox:after {
    top: 95%;
    left: 50%;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, tomato 50%, green 100%);
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="offerBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to solve your problem : using `:before` and `:after` to draw a "box footer" using `skew` to make a triangle, so that you have a responsive and accurate background gradient.

```css
.offerBox {
  position relative;
  width: 360px;
  height: 170px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fcd651 0%, #f9c100 100%);
}

.offerBox:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: -10px;
  content: " ";
  height: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: white;
  transform: skew(45deg);
}

.offerBox:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -10px;
  content: " ";
  height: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: white;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="offerBox"></div>
```

Comment: Very nice! Only disadvantage here is the bottom corners are not rounded.

Comment: Right, there probably is a way though.